# What rule of integration by substitution am I breaking?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

*Context - Method of characteristics to integrate PDE given initial conditions:*

$$ u_t + a u_x + b u = f(t, x) \tag{1a.}$$    $$ u(0, x) = u_0(x) \tag{1b.}$$

I am quoting some intermediate results here for brevity:

The substitution that has been done:
 $$ t \rightarrow \tau \tag{2}$$
 $$ x \rightarrow \xi + a \tau \tag{3}$$
 $$ \widetilde{u}(\tau, \xi) = u(t,x) \tag{4}$$

*a*, *b* are arbitrary constants.

After performing the variable change, the solution to the original PDE **(1a.)** becomes:

$$(e^{bs} \widetilde{u}(s, \xi))|_{s = 0}^{s = \tau} = \int_{0}^{\tau} f(s,\xi + a s) e^{bs} \;ds \tag{5}$$

$$e^{b\tau} \widetilde{u}(\tau, \xi) - \widetilde{u}(0, \xi) = \int_{0}^{\tau} f(s,\xi + a s) e^{bs} \;ds \tag{6}$$
$$e^{b\tau} \widetilde{u}(\tau, \xi) = \widetilde{u}(0, \xi) + \int_{0}^{\tau} f(s,\xi + a s) e^{bs} \;ds \tag{7}$$

The book I am referring to now, after going back to the original variables, substitutes:

$$\widetilde{u}(0, \xi) = u_0(x - a t) $$

I am **not convinced with that substitution** as is $$\widetilde{u}(0, \xi)$$ not evaluated at $$ \tau = 0 $$ and **does it not mean (?) from (2)** that $$t = 0$$

Final expression in the book:

$$e^{bt} u(t, x) = u_{0}(x - a t) + \int_{0}^{t} f(s, x - a(t - s)) e^{bs} \;ds \tag{8}$$

Could someone **please point out what rule of substitution I am breaking**? I also have some problem accepting the final expression involving "*f*"

Thanks!

Comment: These substitutions seem more trouble than they're worth. If you construct the usual characteristic DE system you will arrive at this answer.

Comment: Could you please explain further? Thanks! I have been unable to find a resource that I can understand clearly.

Comment: Hmm. I need some more time to set up an explanation. I tried the way I said at first but for some reason it worked wrong. I followed another path and got it right, but it may not be intuitive and I need to leave now. I'll see if I can answer this in a few hours.